How do I resolve a Next.js static app Dockerfile build error, "Error: Cannot find module [X]" error?
I'm working to create a production Next.js static docker image after successfully setting up a dev docker environment. I'm having a growing list of challenges working through the build. I've followed other related posts that I could find with no luck yet.
Currently, when I run:
# clean out related images for a fresh start
docker rmi -f $(docker images -a -q)

# build and run
docker-compose -f docker-compose.prod.yaml up --build

I see this error:
=> ERROR [ui builder 6/6] RUN npm run build                                                     3.0s
------
 > [ui builder 6/6] RUN npm run build:
0.458 
0.458 > ui@0.1.0 build
0.458 > next build
0.458 
0.803 Attention: Next.js now collects completely anonymous telemetry regarding usage.
0.803 This information is used to shape Next.js' roadmap and prioritize features.
0.803 You can learn more, including how to opt-out if you'd not like to participate in this anonymous program, by visiting the following URL:
0.803 https://nextjs.org/telemetry
0.803 
0.841   ▲ Next.js 14.2.4
0.841 
0.872    Creating an optimized production build ...
2.913 Failed to compile.
2.913 
2.913 src/app/layout.tsx
2.913 An error occurred in `next/font`.
2.913 
2.913 Error: Cannot find module 'tailwindcss'
2.913 Require stack:
2.913 - /home/node/app/node_modules/next/dist/build/webpack/config/blocks/css/plugins.js
2.913 - /home/node/app/node_modules/next/dist/build/webpack/config/blocks/css/index.js
2.913 - /home/node/app/node_modules/next/dist/build/webpack/config/index.js
2.913 - /home/node/app/node_modules/next/dist/build/webpack-config.js
2.913 - /home/node/app/node_modules/next/dist/build/webpack/plugins/next-trace-entrypoints-plugin.js
2.913 - /home/node/app/node_modules/next/dist/build/collect-build-traces.js
2.913 - /home/node/app/node_modules/next/dist/build/index.js
2.913 - /home/node/app/node_modules/next/dist/cli/next-build.js
2.913     at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1090:15)
2.913     at /home/node/app/node_modules/next/dist/server/require-hook.js:55:36
2.913     at Function.resolve (node:internal/modules/helpers:125:19)
2.913     at loadPlugin (/home/node/app/node_modules/next/dist/build/webpack/config/blocks/css/plugins.js:49:32)
2.913     at /home/node/app/node_modules/next/dist/build/webpack/config/blocks/css/plugins.js:157:56
2.913     at Array.map (<anonymous>)
2.913     at getPostCssPlugins (/home/node/app/node_modules/next/dist/build/webpack/config/blocks/css/plugins.js:157:47)
2.913     at async /home/node/app/node_modules/next/dist/build/webpack/config/blocks/css/index.js:124:36
2.913     at async /home/node/app/node_modules/next/dist/build/webpack/loaders/next-font-loader/index.js:86:33
2.913     at async Span.traceAsyncFn (/home/node/app/node_modules/next/dist/trace/trace.js:154:20)
2.913 
2.914 
2.914 > Build failed because of webpack errors
------
failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c npm run build" did not complete successfully: exit code: 1

This reads as a permissions issue to me or files not getting copied over, yet I'm not quite understanding what I need to do for this build yet.
Here's /ui/Dockerfile.prod:
# Build app
FROM node:19 AS builder

# Set working directory
WORKDIR /home/node/app

# Copy package.json and package-lock.json and install dependencies
COPY package.json package-lock.json* ./
RUN npm ci

# Copy the rest of the application files
COPY . .

# Build the Next.js app
RUN npm run build

# Prod image
FROM node:19 AS runner

# Set working directory
WORKDIR /home/node/app

# Copy built files from builder stage
COPY --from=builder /home/node/app/.next ./.next
COPY --from=builder /home/node/app/public ./public
COPY --from=builder /home/node/app/node_modules ./node_modules
COPY --from=builder /home/node/app/package.json ./package.json

# Set environment variables
ENV NODE_ENV=production
ENV PORT=3000

# Expose the port
EXPOSE 3000

# Start the Next.js app
CMD ["npm", "start"]


docker-compose.prod.yaml:
version: '3.8'

services:
    postgres:
        container_name: postgres-prod
        image: postgres:16
        ports:
            - '5432:5432'
        volumes:
            - ./postgresdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data
            - ./src/migrations/dbinit.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/dbinit.sql
        restart: always
        environment:
            POSTGRES_USER: ${POSTGRES_USER}
            POSTGRES_PASSWORD: ${POSTGRES_PASSWORD}
            POSTGRES_DB: ${POSTGRES_DB}
        networks:
            - app-network

    api:
        container_name: api-prod
        image: 'node:19'
        build:
            context: ./server
            dockerfile: Dockerfile.prod
        user: 'node'
        working_dir: /home/node/app
        environment:
            - 'NODE_ENV=${NODE_ENV}'
            - 'PORT=3000'
            - 'DATABASE_URL=${DATABASE_URL}'
        expose:
            - '3000'
        ports:
            - '3000:3000'
        command: 'npm run dev:migrate:start'
        networks:
            - app-network
        depends_on:
            - postgres

    ui:
        container_name: ui-prod
        build:
            context: ./ui
            dockerfile: Dockerfile.prod
        user: 'node'
        working_dir: /home/node/app
        environment:
            - 'NODE_ENV=production'
            - 'NEXT_PUBLIC_API_URL=${NEXT_PUBLIC_API_URL}'
            - 'NEXT_PUBLIC_SOCKET_URL=${NEXT_PUBLIC_SOCKET_URL}'
        ports:
            - '8080:8080'
        command: 'npm start'
        networks:
            - app-network
        depends_on:
            - api

    nginx:
        build:
            context: ./nginx
            dockerfile: Dockerfile.prod
        container_name: nginx-prod
        restart: always
        tty: true
        ports:
            - '80:80'
        networks:
            - app-network
        depends_on:
            - api
            - ui

networks:
    app-network:
        driver: bridge


/ui/package.json:
{
  "name": "ui",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev -p 8080",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start -p 8080",
    "lint": "next lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@auth0/auth0-react": "^2.2.4",
    "next": "14.2.4",
    "react": "^18",
    "react-dom": "^18",
    "socket.io-client": "^4.7.5"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/node": "^20",
    "@types/react": "^18",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18",
    "eslint": "^8",
    "eslint-config-next": "14.2.4",
    "next-image-export-optimizer": "^1.14.1",
    "postcss": "^8",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.4.1",
    "typescript": "^5"
  }
}


I'm running Windows 11 Home, Docker Desktop, initiating build via WSL/Ubuntu.
(note: I noticed that I need to adjust ports, yet that's unrelated).
How do I resolve the Next.js static app Dockerfile build error, "Error: Cannot find module 'tailwindcss'" error?

can you try Add npm install before the build command

https://github.com/vercel/next.js/blob/canary/examples/with-docker/Dockerfile

I'm getting the same error when I add RUN npm install just before RUN npm run build
=> [ui builder 6/7] RUN npm i                                                  1.0s
=> ERROR [ui builder 7/7] RUN npm run build                                    3.4s


I'm looking at the example you sent now @DileepaMabulage. Thank you.

If I copy that example verbatim, I start seeing this error: ```------

[ui runner 7/8] COPY --from=builder --chown=nextjs:nodejs /app/.next/standalone ./:


failed to solve: failed to compute cache key: failed to calculate checksum of ref 6da1a0ef-28bd-4a52-a312-c9dab1bff747::hetdnfrdlu7ny3lq5pdrrox14: "/app/.next/standalone": not found```
So close! I'm digging into this more.

You've corrupted your local Node image.  In the Compose file, delete the line:
services:
  api:
    image: 'node:19'  # <-- DELETE

and manually run
docker pull node:19

and your build should work again.
When your Compose file has both build: and image:, Compose builds the image as described, and then tags it with the specified image: name.  In this setup, you're replacing your local copy of node:19 with the final output of the build; that sets NODE_ENV=production.  When you rebuild it the second time, it starts from the results of the previous build (it does not re-pull the original image), and with NODE_ENV set, it only installs production dependencies.
You should only set build: and image: together if you're planning to push the image to a remote registry like Docker Hub.  In that case the image: is the name of the result image, not the base image.
Many of the other settings in your Compose file either override things that are in the Dockerfile (user:, expose:, command:, environment: [NODE_ENV=...]) or are things Compose can set itself (container_name:, networks:).  You can significantly simplify the Compose file by deleting these as well.

Thank you for the feedback. I felt this was useful for learning and it resolved the build issue. It was interesting that the symptoms were showing in the ui build while the api had image plus build specified (I understand now though).
